# Angularjs single select on ng-dropdown-multiselect

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in angularjs and trying to solve the problem.
My question is how to make single select from ng-dropdown-multiselect I found some of the solutions like:

```
vm.dropDownAreaSelection = {
      selectionLimit: '1',
      closeOnSelect: true,
      displayProp: 'name',
      idProp : 'name',
      showCheckAll : false,
      showUncheckAll : false,
      onChange: vm.filterChangedSelection,
      smartButtonMaxItems: 1,
    };

<div ng-dropdown-multiselect
     options="vm.selectArea"
     selected-model="vm.selected.areaObj"
     extra-settings="vm.dropDownAreaSelection"></div>
```

it's working fine but when I select one item previously selected is not unselected. I'm using angularjs 1.5.3

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ng-dropdown-multiselect fires many event on selection. may be you can clear the model manually.

Comment: Why do you need ng-dropdown-multiselect at all if you only intend to select 1 item?

Comment: Actually it's a big filter already made for ng-dropdown-multiselect, I tried to make select / option code crashed. So I need to fix existing structure.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that selected-model is not an array. It should be object.

```
vm.selected.areaObj = {};
```

For more than 1 selection limit, it should be array.

```
vm.selected.areaObj = [];
```